# Как правильно свзяать локальный узел (Tcp/Udp)Client'a для принятия входящих данных?

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, tcp-ip, torrent

Когда я инициализирую `TcpClient` с указанием в конструкторе `IPAddress` отличного от `0.0.0.0` *(e.g. `IPAddress.Any`)*, то при попытке соединиться с удаленым хостом, происходит исключение:

> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException**: "Сделана попытка выполнить
>   операцию на сокете при отключенной сети ---.---.---.---:----

У меня включена трассировка сети, вот ее лог:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering DNS::GetHostEntry(ヒミコ)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering DNS::GetHostByName(ヒミコ)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting DNS::GetHostByName()     -> IPHostEntry#21950498
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting DNS::GetHostEntry()  -> IPHostEntry#21950498
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering TcpClient#37614147::TcpClient(169.254.93.194:6881#-1034034104)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering Socket#35460724::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting Socket#35460724::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering Socket#35460724::Bind(169.254.93.194:6881#-1034034104)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting Socket#35460724::Bind() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting TcpClient#37614147::TcpClient() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering TcpClient#37614147::BeginConnect(37.146.57.197#-986082779)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering Socket#35460724::BeginConnect(37.146.57.197#-986082779)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering Socket#35460724::BeginConnect(37.146.57.197:6881#-986085180)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Entering Socket#35460724::BeginConnectEx()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting Socket#35460724::BeginConnectEx()    -> ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#65961401
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting Socket#35460724::BeginConnect()  -> ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#65961401
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3192] Exiting TcpClient#37614147::BeginConnect() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9356] Entering TcpClient#37614147::EndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#65961401)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9356] Entering Socket#35460724::EndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#65961401)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9356] Entering Socket#35460724::InternalEndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#65961401)
System.Net.Sockets Error:   0 : [9356] Socket#35460724::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - NetworkUnreachable
```

Я чего-то не до понял, или мне нужно передавать в конструктор сам адрес куда будет идти соединение?

Или как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь подключится к 169.254.93.194. Это [Link-Local адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) - он имеет смысл только в рамках физического сегмента сети - той части LAN, куда воткнут комп с этим адресом.

Пакеты на 169.254.x.x не маршрутизируются, и подключится к нему через интернет (как пытаетесь вы) не получится.

Сокет при попытке открыть такое подключение бросает NetworkUnreachable -
No route to the remote host exists, который в user friendly исключении переведен как "Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети". На самом деле это просто ошибка роутинга.

Судя по вашим вопросам - вы пытаетесь подключится к пиру, выданному вам трекером. Трекер вполне мог выдать те адреса, которые прислали ему пиры, "как есть", не отфильтровывая заведомо недоступные. Просто учитывайте, что часть адресов может в принципе быть невалидной для подключени извне.

Comment: А  вообще тот адрес, что `0.0.0.0` стоит передавать в конструктор? Т.к. я трекеру сообщаю порт на котором буду слушать.

Comment: @ヒミコ это адрес, с которого будут открываться исходящие соединения. Стоит передавать не 0.0.0.0 только в случае, если у вас несколько IP адресов, и надо контролировать, через какой из них пойдет траффик.

Comment: Аа, все теперь понял, документация у MS ужасная.